# How can we enable Logging and String length Special builds in NSIS together?

Tags: logging, nsis

I have found Special builds of NSIS for Advanced Logging and Long Strings but I need to incorporate both into an installer.
I am using NSIS 3.06.1 version.

Currently I am using Dumplog plugin for logging but it doesn't print the automatic detailed logs in case of failure.
So I need to enable Special build for logging but special build for string length is being already used in my Application so I can't use Special build for logging as separate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a example of the plug-in failure?

Comment: Sure, Thank you so much for replying!         ExecWait "INSTDIR\something.exe" $0                               The $0 contains non zero value which shows the above command did not execute successfully.            What I need to display in the log files why it did not execute. It did not print any error log.

Comment: Is something.exe a console application?

Comment: No, it is for example a dot net exe. And also for anything if the execution fails I expect error logs.

Comment: There is no standard for exit codes on Windows even though 0 usually means success. You can check the code yourself and print something but that is off topic for this question.

Comment: Yes but adding the code and printing the logs are bit tricky as there might be many reasons why the command did not execute. I believe Special build for logging would print the errors in case of failure. Is it possible to combine two Special builds in one Application?

Comment: The logging build is not going to tell you anything useful about process launch errors.

Comment: Okay but it gives a lot more other information in the logs unlike dumplog plugin. Is there anyway that we can incorporate two special builds for nsis 3.06.1 version?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to do your own compile of NSIS and include both NSIS_CONFIG_LOG=yes and NSIS_MAX_STRLEN=8192

I am not sure if that BUILD exists, but if someone knows of such, please let us know.